# How can I clone a private submodule in GitLab CI?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a project that runs a .gitlab-ci.yml file, and this project has a private submodule from the same owner. However, when running the job in GitLab CI, it returns an authentication error even though I have the CI variables set.

[image]

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/xxxxxxxx.....
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the token work correctly if you use it in a request from your machine ? (e.g: `curl` with the correct header set)

Comment: Yes, it works correctly in the local environment.

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Please post text as text.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should never explicitly set `CI_JOB_TOKEN` variable in your project settings. This overrides the builtin job token.

Secondly, per the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-submodule-strategy)

> For this feature to work correctly, the submodules must be configured (in .gitmodules) with either:
>
> - the HTTP(S) URL of a publicly-accessible repository, or
> - a relative path to another repository on the same GitLab server. See the Git submodules documentation.

So, if your repository is not public and on the same gitlab server, you can just use the relative path to the project instead of the URL as shown [in the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html#using-relative-urls). It will be authenticated automatically.

```ini
[submodule "project"]
  path = project
  url = ../../project.git
```

---

Additionally, it seems like in your other answer, you've made a solution that does not use the job token.

You can use the job token, too instead. But you need to use the `gitlab-ci-token` user in that case and make sure the token is configured correctly as [documented here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html#configure-cicd-job-token-access).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by removing

```
# GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: 'recursive'
```

from the set of variables and including the global access configuration to the repository with the variables in the 'before script'.

[image]

Now the GitLab CI execution works, and it can clone the private submodule. If there's any other solution, I would like to know. Thank you.